# How to change local user home folder on Windows 2000 and above

Tags: windows, user-management, user-accounts, user-profile, home-directory

I was using a local account on a Windows 7 desktop that is not connected to any Active Directory.

After a while it was required to rename the local account.
Renaming the account was simple using Local users and groups management tool.

After renaming the user, the user home folder was not renamed and I could not find any information about how to change user home folder.

I found the ProfileList registry folder but maybe there is a command line for doing such changes.

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be be able to rename the folder and then updated that information in the "Local path:" field on the "Profile" tab of the user account properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this setting applied as soon as I save it or it requires a restart? I tried to set it before, but nothing happened :)

Comment: For an account/session that is currently active, you will more than likely need to log-off and then log back in for the change to take affect. Probably even better to make the changes while the user is NOT logged in at the time.